# What is missing in the conversion of specific impulse from units of seconds to thrust/mass flow rate?

Tags: rockets, physics, thrust, rocket-equation, specific-impulse

I was trying to get the Specific Impulse of the Saturn V engines, hoping for a value in N/kg/s, as I need to know the mass consumption rate per thrust value. Any and all sources give me the value in seconds: 263s, rather than what I'm looking for. Trying to convert from this unit into N/Kg/s leaves me clueless as I end up at m/s. Now I know dividing velocity by acceleration, g, leaves you with seconds, thus having:
$$s = \frac{N}{kg/s} = \frac{kg\times m}{s^2} \times \frac{s}{kg}= \frac{m}{s}$$
To finish with units of s:
$$s = \frac{m}{s}\times \frac{s^2}{m}$$
Thus,
$$I_{sp}\space\left(\frac{N}{kg/s}\right) = g \times I_{sp}(s)$$

But I can't figure out why you must introduce g into the equation as it doesn't appear during the dimensional analysis. I very well could be missing critical information though which is why I'm here.

Additionally different sources give me different formulas for the Isp itself, some saying it's $\frac{F}{\dot{m}}\space$versus$\space\frac{F*\Delta T}{\dot{m}}.$ The NASA webpage for $I_{sp}$ words the formula as $\frac{Total-Impulse}{\dot{m}* g}$, but the final formula shows as $\frac{F}{\dot{m*g}}$.

Comment: I feel like this has been addressed here more than once. Anyway, Isp is thrust / flow rate, so all you need is 1/Isp to get flow rate / thrust.

Comment: That link eventually help me understand. The thing I was missing was something from the rocket equation itself which is that Veq = F/MFR.

Answer (score 3):

> But I can't figure out why you must introduce g into the equation as it doesn't appear during the dimensional analysis.

g is required because the use of specific impulse in seconds comes from using pounds as both a unit of mass and a unit of force (weight). The conversion factor between pounds-mass and pounds-weight is g.